# ArgumentException: JDBC Driver or DataSource class

Tags: mysql, ejb, datasource, openjpa, geronimo

I'm attempting create a simple web app with a MySQL backend.  I'm able to deploy my .ear in Geronimo.  However, when I submit my form to persist some stuff to the DB via OpenJPA I get the following error (below is my stacktrace):

*Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.*

My Project is an Enterprise Application Project (AReyes) with a web module (AReyesAdminWeb) and an ejb module (AReyesEJB).

### My persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="AReyesPersistUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>AReyesMySql</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.areyes.entity.Admin</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The file is located in AReyesEJB/ejbModule/META-INF

### What I'm using

- Geronimo 2.2.1 with Tomcat 6
- MySQL 5.5.11
- OpenJPA 1.2.2
- Eclipse Indego Release
- OS X 10.6.7

### StackTrace

```
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Error while creating bean com.areyes.session.AdminManager: Error invoking constructor: public com.areyes.session.AdminManager()
    at org.apache.openejb.InjectionProcessor.construct(InjectionProcessor.java:120)
    at org.apache.openejb.InjectionProcessor.createInstance(InjectionProcessor.java:83)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessInstanceManager.ceateInstance(StatelessInstanceManager.java:204)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessInstanceManager.getInstance(StatelessInstanceManager.java:165)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:165)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:217)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:77)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:282)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.xbean.recipe.ConstructionException: Error invoking constructor: public com.areyes.session.AdminManager()
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil$ConstructorFactory.create(ReflectionUtil.java:962)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ObjectRecipe.internalCreate(ObjectRecipe.java:276)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:96)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:61)
    at org.apache.openejb.InjectionProcessor.construct(InjectionProcessor.java:118)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:784)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:561)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1344)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:505)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:430)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:103)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:863)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:854)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:638)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:183)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at com.areyes.session.AdminManager.<init>(AdminManager.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil$ConstructorFactory.create(ReflectionUtil.java:952)
    ... 34 more
```

com.areyes.session.AdminManager is a @Stateless bean that has been injected into a servlet in AReyesAdminWeb (with @EJB anno).  Here's the constrcutor:

```
@Stateless
public class AdminManager implements AdminService {
    private EntityManagerFactory fac;
    private EntityManager em;

    public AdminManager () {
        fac = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AReyesPersistUnit", System.getProperties());
        em = fac.createEntityManager();
    }
```

The behavior seem like my web app is unaware of my persistence.xml in my ejb app.  I wonder if I bundled everything up correctly.

I added this to my application.xml:

```
  <module>
    <connector>tranql-connector-mysql-local-1.5.rar</connector>
  </module>
```

Then I added this to my geronimo-application.xml:

```
<app:module>
    <app:connector>tranql-connector-mysql-local-1.5.rar</app:connector>
    <app:alt-dd>mysql-plan.xml</app:alt-dd>
</app:module>
```

In my EA Project (AReyes) I've added mysql-plan.xml in the same folder with my META-INF.  Then I imported the tranql-connector-mysql-local-1.5.rar from my Geronimo folder.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the web app cannot find persistence.xml on its class path. From reading [this thread](http://marc.info/?l=geronimo-user&m=121248924428569&w=2) you could have the same problem. Try moving persistence.xml to the following location and see how you go...

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Comment: Uable to redeploy when changing my jta-data-source to either examples you have above.  Also, I'm able to execute a CREATE TABLE SQL in the Geronimo console under Services/Database Pool using the AReyesMySql database pool.  So I think my datasource is ok.  Thanks

Comment: Moved my persistence.xml to WEB-INF/classes/META-INF and got the same result.  I tryed the WEB-INF in my dynamic web project (where the servlet and injected ejb is) and my ejb project.  Both were unsuccessful.  Thanks.